# Javascript display current weather in current area

Tags: javascript, weather

I need javascript to get the weather in my current area & then display what it returns as a letter, which would then display an icon since it's a symbol font. ([Climacons font](http://adamwhitcroft.com/climacons/font/)) I'm going to use the [Google API](http://www.google.com/ig/api?hl=en&weather=glenmont) to get the data. I need to use javascript to get the XML line

```
<condition data="_____________"/>
```

in the current_conditions section, and then put that into an array so I can use it to replace that data with a letter to be displayed on the screen. If anyone can help me write a script that can read the XML data & put it into an array, it'd be EXTREMELY helpful!

Comment: What's your question?  Source of data?  Parsing data?  How to display an icon?  Be specific.

Comment: @Brad Basically, I need javascript to get the weather in my current area & then display what it returns as a letter, which would then display an icon since it's a symbol font. (Climacons font)

Comment: You've said that, but you haven't said which part you're having trouble with.  Also, does it need to work internationally?

Answer (score 0):

You could call a weather api ( http://www.programmableweb.com/apitag/weather?format=JSON ) and get some json data.

Then manipulate that into your interface.

Comment: I like the [Google Weather API](http://www.google.com/ig/api?hl=en&weather=nyc) more. JSON, custom language, images included.

Comment: I was going to specifically mention that one as it's my fav too but the xml means more work.

Comment: Why xml means more work? I am using jQuery and it helps me a lot `:D`

Comment: I'm kinda new to coding.. I'm only fluent in HTML & CSS, learning javascript but I'm not very good. Would anyone be able to help me out..

Comment: Have a look at those api's and try call one and get some data to work with first. Then mangle the data into shape to fit with your single letter codes and then you should be able to apply it. jQuery makes stuff like this pretty simple if you haven't used it yet.

Comment: To use the Google Weather APi, because of the stupid cross-domain thing, you will have to use PHP to get the data.

Comment: I can't use PHP, and I can't figure out how to fetch data from an API & put it into an array that gets replaced with a letter, that's why I asked my question here..